# Unable to add users to a folder which have unique permision. Error "sharing folders is disabled"

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sharing

I have a classic team site collection inside our SharePoint online, the site collection has publishing features enabled at the site collection and site levels. now inside a folder >> i stop the permission inheritance >> but when i try to grant a user access to the folder, i got this error:-

[image]

any advice? why SharePoint is allowing me to break the permission without allowing me to add users to the folder?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate way to overcome this issue, we can add user or group at the site level, then on folder level  apply "**stop inheriting permission**",  finally remove all users or groups which you do not need at the folder level, and retain the one which you want to assign permissions. And also, try deactivating the feature "**Limited-access user permission lockdown mode"**  this might fix the issue. So, before  following the above work around, try to deactivate the limited access feature and see the result.

Comment: but what is the implication of deactivating the feature "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode"? Second point, for adding the user to the site level, i do not think this will work,as i have to remove those users from hundreds of folders..

Comment: If you enable limited access user permission lockdown mode, and share the folder with the user, they will get access denied error. Please read the msdn document here : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sharing-and-permissions/cannot-access-shared-folder   and for adding user or group in site level will not be a optimal solution when you multiple folders which needs cumbersome efforts, I agree with you. :-)

Comment: i read this link but it mentioned `Other features such as publishing may require this feature to work correctly.` and in our case we have the publishing features enabled.. so i am not sure if i can or if i should disable the `"Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" ` feature ?

Comment: Try to implement this in a test site, if no side impact of limited access.... feature, then implement in the main site.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with deactivating the feature "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" and it does not affect the publish feature in my environment.